# Cloud Firestore subcollection query via REST

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection `x`, each document of `x` has subcollection `y`. Each document of `y` has a `time` attribute. I can't figure out how to query *just* that subcollection via REST (I know this feature exists in the SDK). My query so far, which is obviously wrong:

```
{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
      {
        "collectionId": "x",
        "allDescendants": true
      }
    ],
    "where": {
      "compositeFilter": {
        "op": "AND",
        "filters": [
          {
            "fieldFilter": {
              "field": {
                "fieldPath": "y.time"
              },
              "op": "GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL",
              "value": {
                "integerValue": 1577836800000
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "fieldFilter": {
              "field": {
                "fieldPath": "y.time"
              },
              "op": "LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL",
              "value": {
                "integerValue": 1578355200000
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sending a POST to `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT/databases/{default}/documents:runQuery`, but I've also tried `.../documents/x/ID/y:runQuery` but that's obviously wrong too.

Comment: I would contact Firebase support directly and they pass the question on to engineering staff.  If you get an answer, from them, then you can post it back here for everyone to use.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I did just that, and Firebase support told me to post on SO. What a world.

Comment: I would insist to support that there is no documentation or examples explaining how to do this, and given no documentation or examples, the community can not be expected to know how to do this.

Comment: I will also suggest that, if Firebase support says it's just not possible to query a subcollection with the REST API, that this is effectively a feature request to match the features provided by the client SDKs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you described a [collection group query](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) for collection group `y`. In the REST API, this is an `allDescendants` query on the path `projects/PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents` (known as the root document):

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery

{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
      {
        "collectionId": "y",
        "allDescendants": true
      }
    ],
    "where": {
      "compositeFilter": {
        "op": "AND",
        "filters": [
          {
            "fieldFilter": {
              "field": {
                "fieldPath": "time"
              },
              "op": "GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL",
              "value": {
                "integerValue": 1577836800000
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "fieldFilter": {
              "field": {
                "fieldPath": "time"
              },
              "op": "LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL",
              "value": {
                "integerValue": 1578355200000
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the path to the subcollection in the URL:

`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/x/documentX:runQuery`

Then make the collectionId in `from` collection "y" and `allDescendants` false:

```
{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
      {
        "collectionId": "y",
        "allDescendants": false
      }
    ],
    "where": {
      "compositeFilter": {
        "op": "AND",
        "filters": [
          {
            "fieldFilter": {
              "field": {
                "fieldPath": "y.time"
              },
              "op": "GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL",
              "value": {
                "integerValue": 1577836800000
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "fieldFilter": {
              "field": {
                "fieldPath": "y.time"
              },
              "op": "LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL",
              "value": {
                "integerValue": 1578355200000
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery#path-parameters

Comment: This is works. Thanks! You need to add the parent document path of the subcollection to the url.